# If JNI DeleteGlobalRef() is called, does the corresponding java object get garbage collected?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

What I mean is, if I create a global reference jobject in C++, and then pass that off to some Java code, and delete call DeleteGlobalRef(), is that underlying java object potentially garbage collected right away, so that any future Java code that is already refering to that object might come back with a NullPointerException?  Specifically, if I have some C++ code that does something like this simplified example:

```
static jobject myObjGlobalRef;
static JNIEnv* env = /* call to create a JVM and get the JNI env */;
jobject ReturnMyObj()
{
    /* <<Code that defines class, constructorId, and param1 goes here>> */

    jobject localObj = env->NewObject(class, constructorId, param1);
    myObjGlobalRef = env->NewGlobalRef(localObj);
}

void DeleteMyObj()
{
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(myObjGlobalRef);
}

myObjGlobalRef = ReturnMyObj();

jobject otherExistingGlobalRef = /* Assume we get another global ref to another parent obj somewhere else */
/*  ... other code here ... */
// Invoke some method on some other pre-existing global reference that uses
// myObjGlobalRef,  lets assume this method stores the object referenced by
// myObjGlobalRef into a parent object referenced by otherExistingGlobalRef:
env->CallVoidMethod(env, otherExistingGlobalRef, addASubObjectMethodId, myObjGlobalRef);

DeleteMyObj();

// Does the pointed to by myObjGlobalRef still exist here, assuming that
// otherExistingGlobalRef now references it?
```

How does this work in JNI?  Is a "GlobalReference" on an object just a reference count to the object, so that if I free the GlobalReference jobject, it does not necessarily garbage collect the underlying java object until all references to it (such as the "parent" object otherExistingGlobalRef referencing it) are gone?

If you can answer this and provide a link to some official Java/Sun/Oracle documentation backing up your answer, you earn bonus kudos :-).

Comment: You might want to read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html?  They mention some useful tips about this subject.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DeleteGlobalRef() frees the *reference*, not the object.

If that was the last reachable reference, then the referenced object is available for garbage collection.

> Is a "GlobalReference" on an object just a reference count to the object

No. It's just a reference that remains valid until you free it explicitly. Java's garbage collection does not rely on reference counts at all.

See also [Oracle's documentation on global references](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242).

Comment: This was my hunch, and I've seen that particular Oracle page before, but it didn't give me a warm fuzzy regarding references.  However, you piqued my brain to go searching, and I found this link: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html about Java garbage collection and references.  If can we assume a JNI global reference is treated the same as any other Java (strong) reference, that helps me feel better about your answer.

Comment: I was looking for an introduction to Java GC for you, glad you found one. The doc for DeleteGlobalRef() says specifically "Deletes the global *reference* pointed to by globalRef." My experience has been that this is accurate; and if it were not, bad things would happen. :)

Comment: For future reference, the sun.com link in my comment is dead.  But the name of the paper book with some nice GC and reference information is "Java™ Platform Performance: Strategies and Tactics" by S. Wilson and J. Kesselman, if anyone is interested in tracking down more info on the subject.  (You may be able to find an electronic copy online if you dig around enough).