# Can Java layer object be released by JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface

I create a Java object by calling native code which return a jobject value.

Java code:

```
Object myObj = nativeCreateObject();
```

Native code:

```
jobject* hold_ref;
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
nativeCreateObject(JNIEnv *env ...) {
    .....
    result = env->NewGlobalRef(jobj);
    hold_ref = &result;
    return result;
}
```

my question is: whether I can use hold_ref later to release the myObj by reference in native layer?
e.g.
native code:

```
*hold_ref = NULL;
```

Then the myObj in Java layer is null?
if not, how can I release this object by native code?

Comment: No. You need to read [chapter 4 of the JNI Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_and_local_references).

Comment: @EJP thanks for the information. After reading...I still didn't find the answer. Could you please help to briefly give me some advice about this question?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `result` and `myObj` are two different references to the same object. The object can't be garbage collected as long as at least one reference to it exists. _Maybe_ you could wrap the result of `nativeCreateObject` in a `WeakReference` in Java (it's not something I've ever tried, so I'm not making any guarantees). By the way, `*hold_ref = NULL;` is not how you delete a global reference.

Comment: This seems apropos:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337494/if-jni-deleteglobalref-is-called-does-the-corresponding-java-object-get-garba

Comment: Why does this concern you? Can't the object be treated just like every other object created in your Java program? (Of course, you could have a global reference leak: In nativeCreateObject, you ignored hold_ref's current value before setting it to a new one. And, you might need to be concern with multiple threads accessing hold_ref.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, what you want to achieve, but here is how it basicly works:

> whether I can use hold_ref later to release the myObj by reference in native layer?

Yes, you can and should use `env->DeleteGlobalRef(myObj)` to free the global reference you have created so the garbage collector can clean up and finaly destroy the object.

> Then the myObj in Java layer is null? if not, how can I release this object by native code?

There is no way your Java-variable will turn null magicaly when you delete the reference from jni native code. Java itself holds a reference to prevent the object is removed by the garbage collection.

You may want to use it this way:

C++

```
jobject* hold_ref;

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL nativeCreateObject(JNIEnv *env ...) {
   .....
   result = env->NewGlobalRef(jobj);
   hold_ref = &result;
   return result;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL nativeDestroyObject(JNIEnv *env ...) {
   .....
   env->DeleteGlobalRef(jobj);
   hold_ref = nullptr;
}
```

JAVA

```
// Creates two references (native and local variable)
Object myObj = nativeCreateObject();

// Deletes the native reference, but not the local one
nativeDeleteObject(myObj);
// myObj != null

myObj = null;
// now there is no reference to your created object
// the garbage collector may destroy it any time
```

If you want to invalidate your object in someway I suggest to manage the state and throw an exception, if the object was invalidated like this:

```
class MyInvalidateableObject {

    private boolean invalidated = false;

    public void invalidate() {
        this.invalidated = true;
    }

    public void foo() {
        if (invalidated) 
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object has been invalidated");
        ... // do the normal stuff
    }
}
```

Simply call `invalidate()` on your object from native code to prevent it from being used anymore.